# If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pm \infty}\sqrt{|x|}(f(x)- cos(x))=1$ is continous, it is uniformly continous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

There is a continous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pm \infty}\sqrt{|x|}(f(x)- \cos(x))=1$. Prove that function $f$ is uniformly continous.

I know that there are proofs on this forum that if $g$ is bounded and continous, $g$ is uniformly continous, but I don't know how to apply those to my situation.

Maybe I need to show that if function if $\sqrt{|x|}(f(x)- \cos(x))$ is bounded then $f$ is bounded?

Comment: Bounded and continuous does not imply uniformly continuous. Continuous on a compact does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Principle

This is a really lovely problem, a case of "small $x$ , big $x$". The existence of the limit pretty much decides $f(x)$ for large values of $x$, while for small values of $x$ uniform continuity follows from the fact that a continuous function on a compact(same as closed and bounded) interval  is uniformly continuous.

Another point : it is true that $f$ is bounded, but we can actually derive the stronger statement that it is uniformly continuous without requiring this fact.

Let's quickly note that if
$
\sqrt{|x|}{(f(x)-\cos x)} \to 1
$
then for large $x$, $f(x)-\cos x \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ i.e. $f(x)$ behaves like $\cos x$ for large enough $x$. Because $\cos(x)$ is uniformly continuous (this is not difficult to prove from its periodicity), we would then expect the same from $f$.

The fundamental quantity to control for uniform continuity is $|f(x)-f(y)|$. So we want to express $f(x)-f(y)$ in terms of the approximation we have obtained. We use a split-into-three inequality , often called an $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ split. The aim of this inequality is this : $f(x)$ is close to $\cos(x)$, $f(y)$ is close to $\cos(y)$ and $\cos(x)$ is close to $\cos(y)$. It's like : showing $f$ values are close, is *transferred* to showing that $\cos$ values are close, which we know is true.

This bounds $f(x)-f(y)$ for large enough $x,y$ close enough, which is all we need.

##### The large $x$ values

Let $x,y \in \mathbb R$ and $\epsilon>0$. Note the inequality :
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |f(x)-\cos(x)|+|\cos(x) - \cos(y)| + |f(y)-\cos(y)| \tag{1}
$$

which is true for all $x,y$.

First : by uniform continuity of $\cos(x)$, there is a $\delta_1>0$ such that for all $|x'-y'|<\delta_1$ we have $|\cos(x')-\cos(y')| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

Now, for the other two terms we use the limit : let's see what it means. For every $\epsilon'>0$ there is $r'>0$ large enough such that $|x|>r'$ implies $|\sqrt{|x|}(f(x)-\cos(x))-1| < \epsilon'$. That is, $\frac{1-\epsilon'}{\sqrt{|x|}}<|f(x)-\cos(x)| <\frac{1+\epsilon'}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ from the triangle inequality.

This is helpful! Let's take $\epsilon'=1$, and so we get $r'>0$ such that the above happens. In particular, $|f(x)-\cos(x)| < \frac{2}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ for all $|x|>r'$.

But now life is simple : take $r''>0$ such that $\frac{2}{\sqrt{|x|}} < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for all $|x|>r''$. Then if $r = \max\{r',r''\}$, $|x|>r$ implies that $|f(x)-\cos(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

Finally, the following is true by $(1)$ :

> For all $x,y$ with $|x|,|y|>r$ and $|x-y| < \delta_1$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

##### Small values

We never used the fact that $f$ is continuous above, so where does it come into play? For *small values*. The following result is standard, and hopefully has been studied. If not, I will attach the required links.

> A continuous function on a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous.

We apply this, to $f$ restricted to $[-r-\delta_1,r+\delta_1]$ , where $r$ is coming from the previous argument. Of course this is closed and bounded, and $f$ is continuous, hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on this interval. You'll see why I added the $\delta_1$ part in some time.

Thus, for the given $\epsilon$, we have a $\delta_2 >0$ such that for all $|x-y| < \delta_2$ and $x,y \in [-r-\delta_1,r+\delta_1]$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

##### Conclusion

To conclude, we need to patch these up. Let $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. If $|x-y| < \delta$, there are three possibilities :

- $|x|,|y|<r$. We use the "small values" discussion to conclude that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.
- $|x|,|y|>r$. We use the "large values" discussion to conclude that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.
- One of $|x|,|y| < r$ and other is $>r$. Say $|x|<r$. Then, because $|x-y|<\delta \leq \delta_1$, we get by the triangle inequality that $|x|,|y| < r+\delta_1$, and hence the "small values discussion" applies (can you now see why the interval was extended?) to conclude that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

##### Principles to be kept in mind

- Using limits to control large values of $f(x)$.
- Using the $\frac \epsilon 3$ method to transfer closeness of $f$ to closeness of $\cos$, allowing us to use the uniform continuity of $\cos$.
- Controlling small values of $x$ using a result about continuity on closed and bounded intervals.
- Extending the interval by a $\delta_1$ factor to "patch" the two arguments together.

---

##### Sidenote

Please let me know if you do not know either of these facts, which should have been proved prior to the introduction of this question :

- $\cos(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.
- A continuous function defined on a closed and bounded interval of $\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous.

I can direct you to sources, or we can have a conversation about why these are true.

##### Edit

To see that $\cos$ is uniformly continuous, we note that it has a period of $2 \pi$. Therefore, controlling it in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ is enough. But we again need to do a little "patching", so the interval is not quite $[0,2 \pi]$ for a "small" situation.

More precisely : note that $\cos$ is continuous and $[0,4\pi]$ is uniformly bounded, therefore $\cos$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,4\pi]$. Now, let $\epsilon>0$. There exists a $\delta>0$ such that for $x,y \in [0,4 \pi]$ we have $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|\cos(x) - \cos(y)| < \epsilon$.

Now, let $x,y$ be arbitrary. We can, by subtracting multiples of $2 \pi$, ensure that there is are $x'$ and $y'$ in $[0,4 \pi]$ such that $x'-x$ and $y'-y$ are integer multiples of $2 \pi$, so that $f(x) = f(x')$ and $f(y) = f(y')$. Now, suppose that $|x-y|<\delta$. Prove that $x',y'$ can be chosen such that $|x'-y'|<\delta$, then by uniform continuity $|f(x) - f(y)| = |f(x')-f(y')| < \epsilon$. So this $\delta$ always works and we are done.

Comment: Wonderful answer! As a small nitpick, I think in the "small values" discussion you have an $[-r-2\delta_1, r+2\delta_1]$ which should be $[-r-\delta_1, r+\delta_1]$ (?)

Comment: @ClementC. Ouch! I actually meant to thicken the range to $2 \delta_1$ because I was not sure how much I needed to patch the two parts together. Thank you, I realize now I just needed to patch by $\delta_1$.

Comment: As I said, this was only a *minor* nitpick. Really great and instructive answer!

Comment: @ClementC. I had real fun writing this answer. I will suggest it to somebody I know for a real analysis exam, because there are so many small things you need to take care of. I am just waiting for OPs reply.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, I am sorry for delay. I will look at it in couple of hours, hope you're not in rush. I had no time to do that earlier because I saw that your answer is so detailed and thought that I would need some free time to evaluate it. Just didn't expect my original question to be that deep, I suppose. I found it in a random book on analysis. Nevertheless, needless to say, I am very grateful for your contribution and I am happy that you liked that exercise (sorry for my English).

Comment: @mathp The question is not really *that* deep, it is just that it carries with it a lot of subtlety that goes just a little underappreciated at an undergraduate level. I really liked answering your question! Your English is better than mine, then again English is my third language so that is expected a little bit.

Comment: I have just written your answer and I like it! I will think of it some time more, but I suppose I understand it for the most part. I know that $\cos(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and that a continuous function defined on a closed and bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous. I always have taken the first of those 2 facts as given and the second one was indeed presented on the course of analysis. I think that I could use some materials on the first one them, if that's not a problem :)

Comment: @mathp Would you like a proof that $\cos$ is uniformly continuous? I can provide that.

Comment: Yeah, if I could. And additionally, how do you know (1) inequality is true for all x?

Comment: @mathp I will do that. Also, the inequality $(1)$ comes from the fact that $f(x) - f(y) = (f(x) - \cos(x)) + (\cos(x) - \cos(y)) + (\cos y - f(y))$, which you can see easily by seeing cancellations. Apply the triangle inequality to this , you get $(1)$.

Comment: @mathp Edited answer to include uniform continuity of $\cos$. It is not the most precise answer of all time, but it does the job.

Comment: I love it. I will do some more exercises on uniform continuity to fully understand it on other functions as well. Thank you once again.

Comment: @mathp You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is a streamlined version of Teresa Lisbon's proof.

In fact,
$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\sqrt{|x|}(f(x)-\cos(x))=1
\implies \lim_{x\to\pm\infty}(f(x)-\cos(x))=0.$$
So for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $X_0>0$ such that
when $|x|\geq X_0$,
$$|f(x)-\cos(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}.$$
The function $\cos x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$,
there exists $\delta>0$ such that when $|x_2-x_1|<\delta$,
$$|\cos x_2-\cos x_1|<\frac\epsilon 3.$$
For any $x_1,x_2\in[X_0,+\infty)$, when $|x_2-x_1|<\delta$,
$$|f(x_2)-f(x_1)|\leq |f(x_2)-\cos x_2|+|\cos x_2-\cos x_1|+|f(x_1)-\cos x_1|
<\epsilon.$$
So $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[X_0,+\infty)$.

> In the same way, we can prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,-X_0]$.

> By Cantor's theorem, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[-X_0,X_0]$.

So the function $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you for streamlining it, Riemann. +1